# Show image if rank equals number

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a row of 5 cells. I want to show an image above each cell depending on the rank of the cell. So if the rank of the cell equals 1, show a specific image (from a link), if the rank is 2, show a different image, and so on.

Here is what my sheet looks like now:

```
+-------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Image |      |      |      |      |      |
+-------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Score |  100 |  300 |  200 |  500 |  400 |
+-------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Do you have image urls list somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a table with rank numbers and corresponding image URLs (columns `A:B` im my example).

Put this formula in place of header **Image** (above the header **Rank**):

```
={
  "Image",
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    IMAGE(
      VLOOKUP(
        RANK(F3:J3, F3:J3),
        A2:B,
        2,
        0
      )
    )
  )
}
```

[image]